# Create list of row elements - Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to create a column B from Column A elements as shown below in panadas dataframe.
C[image]

Can anyone please help?

I basically want to calculate rolling median for Column 'A' . Can anyone tell the alternative of column B as well to calculate the same

Comment: @jezrael this one (if wanted) would also be a dupe, I'll add it later today

Comment: @mozway - You forget add link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If need lists use [`Series.expanding`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.expanding.html) in list comprehension:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':range(1, 7)})

df['B'] = [x.tolist() for x in df.A.expanding()]
print (df)
   A                   B
0  1                 [1]
1  2              [1, 2]
2  3           [1, 2, 3]
3  4        [1, 2, 3, 4]
4  5     [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
5  6  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Alternative:

```
L = df.A.tolist()
df['B'] = [L[:i] for i, x in enumerate(L,1)]
```

If need median use [`Expanding.median`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.window.Expanding.median.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':range(1, 7)})

df['B'] = df.A.expanding().median()
print (df)
   A    B
0  1  1.0
1  2  1.5
2  3  2.0
3  4  2.5
4  5  3.0
5  6  3.5
```